# If I initial ExtJS tree without children, How to add them later?

Tags: extjs, tree

I try to add children to root node with this command.

`tree.root.appendChild({ text : 'xxx' });`

It doesn't work for no-children tree.
In other way, It work when I do this with tree that already initial with children node.

Thank you.

Comment: Your approach looks fine. So, show us your code and we might be able to help you.

Comment: I misunderstand @Chau, I try again and everything work. Thanks for response.

Comment: Then I suggest that you delete this question - since it has no relevance to others.

Comment: I try to re-check my work and un-work code, The difference is when I set TreePanel.rootVisible = false, It suddenly work. But If rootVisible is true, I can't appendChild to that (In no-child initial case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below command.

```
Ext.getCmp('treepanelId').getRootNode().appendChild({ text : 'xxx' });
Ext.getCmp('treepanelId').doLayout();
```